# Why doesn't my servlet load on TomCat 6.0.18 but loads fine on 5.5

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6

I have a development environment where i use TomCat 5.5 and my application works fine. As soon as a transfer everything to a deployment server, that's running TomCat 6.0.18, a servlet class called DeviceComm doesn't seem to load. The error that i'm getting in "Ressource not available".

I have brought modifications to this class recently. The transfer was only an update, everything was working fine before. Basically, the question is: what can make a servlet not work on version 6 of tomcat and work fine on 5.5 ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace for the error?

Comment: Problem solved! 
The deployment .class files were not the same as the ones on the development environment. Bug in SourceSafe!

Comment: welcome to SO!  Could you create a new answer to your question that says what your comment says, and then mark it as accepted (click the outline of a checkmark on the left)?  That just helps keep things in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! The deployment .class files were not the same as the ones on the development environment. Bug in SourceSafe!

Comment: So, reading the server logs didn't at all help in solving the problem?

Answer (score 3):

That can be caused by everything. Read the server startup logs. It's located in the `/logs` folder with the filename `domainname.yyyy-MM-dd.log`. It'll contain any exceptions/problems which are occurred during server startup and servlet initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you just did not copy your `server.xml` file from 5.5 to 6.0.  There are quite a few subtle differences in 6.0 that makes 5.5 `server.xml` to not load.

Make sure that you apply your configuration changes to 6.0 template that comes with tomcat distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be a JDK version mismatch if your Tomcat 5.5 runs on Java 5 and the Tomcat 6 runs on Java 6